# Current through Capacitor, how is it possible? How does it relate to displacement current?

Tags: capacitor, current

What my professor is telling us that there is no conduction current through a parallel plate capacitor but the current that is passing through capacitor is the displacement current and this phenomena can be seen in one of the Maxwell's equation. What I know about displacement current is that there is no charge movement in displacement current but I am so confused with that. Can some one explain me the displacement current and how does it work in parallel plate capacitor?

Comment: Do check Dave's EEVblog with exactly that as a topic: EEVblog #486 - Does Current Flow Through A Capacitor? ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppWBwZS4e7A))